# Streaming downloads via Google drive v2 API

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm using the .net implementation of the v2 library.

I successfully obtaining the file metadata and download Url's for files but when I start to stream down in chunks I'm noticing that most of the time they are streaming down to my server in 1.3k blocks and if lucky this rate increases to 16k even though I ask the stream to provide 1Mb of info.

Do Google limit streaming capabilities from their download servers? is there a way I can improve this performance as I'm creating a SaaS product and this could cripple my capabilities - especially when I'm pcking multiple files into a single streaming zip :|

At the moment I'm flushing to my clients after processing each received block, but I'm considering buffering a bit before streaming down if I can't find a way of improving file performance from Google's side!

any help advice would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive is not intended to be used for streaming content, and there are no options that allow you to control the rate at while data is transmitted to your client.